# App Engine loading request even when idle instance available

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have a simple app running on App Engine but I'm having odd problems with latency. It's a Python 2.7 app and a loading request takes between 1.5 and 10 secs (I guess depending on how GAE is feeling). This is a low traffic site right now, so previously GAE was sitting with no idle instances and most request were loading requests, resulting in a long wait time on the first page view.

I've tried configuring the minimum number of idle instances to "1" so that these infrequent page views can immediately hit a warm instance.

However, I've seen several cases now where even with one instance sitting unused, GAE will route an incoming request to a loading instance, leaving the warm instance untouched:

[gae dashboard showing odd scheduling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFl2g.png)

How can I prevent this from happening? I feel I must be understanding something wrong, because I certainly don't expect this behavior.

**Update**: Also, what makes this even less comprehensible is that the app has threadsafe enabled, so I really don't understand why GAE would get flustered and spin up an instance for a single, lone request.

Comment: I've seen the same behavior as well, but haven't found a reason for it.

Comment: It's very dissapointing to see the same behavior 7 years later

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe this is normal behavior. Idle instances are supposed to guarantee a minimum number of instances always available (for spiky load).

So, when some requests start coming in, they are initially served by idle instances, but at the same time AE scheduler will start launching new instances to always guarantee the same amount of idle instances even during suddenly increased load. That is, to "cover" for those idle instances that became busy serving requests.

It is described in details on [Adjusting Application Performance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) page.

Comment: I included that screenshot because it shows how a single, lone request was forwarded to a new instance even while an idle instance sat unused. Even if GAE was trying to maintain a single idle instance, why is it blocking a request that could be immediately served while the new instance loads?

Answer (score 0):

Arrrgh! Suffer from this myself. This topic-area has come up in several threads (GAE groups & SO). If someone can dial-in the settings for a low-traffic site (billing on/off), that would be a real benefit. IIRC, someone with what I think is deep GAE experience noted in one thread that the Scheduler does not do well with very low volume apps. I have also seen wildly different startup times within a relatively short period of time. Painful to see a spinup take 700ms then 7000ms just a few minutes later. Overall the issue is not so much the cost to me, but more so the waste of infrastructure resources. In testing I've had two instances running despite having pinged the app with an RPC once every few minutes. If 50k other developers are similarly testing, that could accumulate into a significant waste.

Comment: I got frustrated and tried turning `min idle instances` down to Automatic and then pinging with cron.yaml tasks every 5-11 minutes...App Engine decided to spin up three instances to handle my sub 0.5 QPS artificial traffic. So I guess the scheduler just doesn't know how to handle low traffic. That's very disappointing.